# Show undefined a variable in react

Tags: reactjs

when it shows the array in the console it shows correctly. when I moved venueId into a variable it shows as undefined.I have added the whole code it works on this line `const venueid = this.state.venueData[0].venueId` on `getShowTimes` function

```
export  class EventDetails extends Component {
    
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            venueData : [],
            venueID: 0,
            venueDataLoaded: false,
            showTimesData : [],
            showTimeDataLoaded : false,
        }
}

        getVenues = async(eventData) => {
            try{
            const requestOptions = {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'client_token': 'ebd86470-7e90-4ece-9e89-1b6d4d2cbb61' }
            };
            await fetch(
                // `http://595977570d12.ngrok.io/v1/seat?venueId=`+ movieData.venueId + `&movieId=`+ movieData.Mid + 
                //     `&showtimeId=` + movieData.showtimeId + `&movieDate=2021-08-05`
                `${process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_BASE_URL}/v1/movie/` + eventData.movieid + `/venues`, requestOptions)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then((venueList) => {
                    console.log(venueList.data.venues)
                    this.setState({ 
                        venueData: venueList.data.venues,
                        venueDataLoaded: true,
                    })
                    console.log(this.state.venueData)
                    this.getShowTimes(eventData)
                }).catch(console.log);
            }
            catch (error) {
            console.log("error", error)
            }
        }

        getShowTimes = async(eventData) => {
            try{
                const requestOptions = {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'client_token': 'ebd86470-7e90-4ece-9e89-1b6d4d2cbb61' }
                };
                console.log(this.state.venueData)
                const venueid = this.state.venueData[0].venueId
                venueinfomation = venueid
                await fetch(
                    `${process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_BASE_URL}/v1/movie/` + eventData.movieid + `/venue/` + venueid + `/showtime`, requestOptions)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then((showTimes) => {
                        console.log(showTimes.data.dateShowtimes)
                        this.setState({ 
                            showTimesData: showTimes.data.dateShowtimes,
                            showTimeDataLoaded: true,
                        })
                        console.log(this.state.showTimesData)
                    }).catch(console.log);
                }
                catch (error) {
                console.log("error", error)
                }
        }


    componentDidMount(){
        let eventDetails = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search)
        console.log(eventDetails.movieid) 
        this.setState(eventDetails)
        console.log(eventDetails.name) 
        eventData = eventDetails
        this.getVenues(eventDetails)
    }

    render(){
        console.log(this.state.showTimesData)
        let showVenueData = this.state.showTimesData
        console.log(showVenueData)
        console.log(venueinfomation)
        const vn = this.state.venueData.venueId
        console.log(vn)
        return(
```

output of `this.state.venueData[0]`

```
{venueId: 377, venue: 'Youth Center Main Auditorium', startDate: '2022-10-11', endDate: '2022-10-11', bookingOpenDate: '2018-05-18', …}
```

[image: output]
[image: code]
[image: error]

Comment: is venueData[0] a JSON or a stringified JSON? Can you check with `typeof`?

Comment: What shows ```console.log(this.state.venueData[0].venueId)``` ?

Comment: it shows venueId as undifined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'venueId')

Comment: can you please post the whole code once along with the error

Comment: Are you fetching this state when the component mounts?

Comment: yes im getting it when component mounts

Comment: We need more code, but could it be that venueData is not an array? does this.state.venueData.venueId work?

Comment: I think @Poku is right, can you do `console.log(this.state.venueData, typeof this.state.venueData)`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `async await` syntax in your code, it takes some time to get the data. When the component firstly loads, `this.state.venueData` is an empty array, so `this.state.venueData[0]` is `undefined`. And you are trying to get the `venueId` of `undefined`. Try using conditions, like `if (this.state.venueData[0]) { ... }`
Hope this helps!